# #ifdef KERNEL2x & file_operations(..,..,..,..) , ssize_t function,printk()

Tags: c, module, driver

Hi I have several questions. I will be glad if someone will answer :)
I'm trying to compile linux driver for an lcd 16X2 module.
I'm trying to use in my code the struct file_operations();
1. I notice by other codes that they add #ifdef KERNEL21 to compile. I tryed to this and I got much less errors. why it's work this way. im using kernel 2.6.18-128.4.1.el5.. soo do I need to change to #ifdef KERNEL26? I get more errors if I try to do soo.

2.some of the file_operation arguments are function the rtuen ssize_t. what is this mean? in other code eample there is also "#ifdef KERNEL21" but still I get an error:
"lcd_module.c:74: error: expected identifier or ג(ג before ג{ג token"

3.last qustion, I worked with a Makfile example and I get .o file and not .ko that im use to work with. how do I run the module with the .o file?

thank on advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssize_t` is basically a signed `size_t` and is widely used in the kernel because values less than zero are used to return errors in places where an unsigned size is expected. For example, the `read` file operation is expected to return the number of bytes read, but in case of insufficient memory you can return `-ENOMEM` and `errno` will be set appropriately in the user-space program.

With the 2.6 kernel you are supposed to use the Makefile from the `kernel-headers` package rather than a hand-crafted one, and it produces a `.ko` file rather than an `.o`. Further reading here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html